# Write large json object by chunks using cordova file plugin

Tags: android, json, file, cordova

I need to write a large json object in a file inside an Android cordova app.

To do so, I have added **cordova-plugin-file** and used the following code :

```
var getStorage = function() {
  return LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT;
};

var requestFileSystem = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    window.requestFileSystem(getStorage(), 0, resolve, reject);
  });
};

var getFileEntry = function(fileName) {
  var options = {
    create: true,
    exclusive: false
  };

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    requestFileSystem()
      .then(function(fs) {
        fs.root.getFile(fileName, options, resolve, reject);
      })
      .catch(reject);
  });
};

var writeFile = function(fileName, data) {
    data = data || {}; // default value if none

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      getFileEntry(fileName)
        .then(function(fileEntry) {
          fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

            fileWriter.onwriteend = resolve;
            fileWriter.onerror = reject;

            fileWriter.write(JSON.stringify(data));
          });
        })
        .catch(reject);
    });
};

// suppose largeJsonObject is initialized and extremely large
writeFile('file.json', largeJsonObject);
```

When I try to do so, I have the following java exception :

```
11-03 11:03:54.368 14412 14497 I art     : Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-03 11:03:54.368 14412 14497 I art     : Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-03 11:03:54.378 14412 14497 I art     : Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(192B) AllocSpace objects, 1(23MB) LOS objects, 15% free, 88MB/104MB, paused 241us total 10.730ms
11-03 11:03:54.378 14412 14497 I art     : Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-03 11:03:54.378 14412 14497 I art     : Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-03 11:03:54.388 14412 14497 I art     : Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 15% free, 88MB/104MB, paused 248us total 9.610ms
11-03 11:03:54.388 14412 14497 I art     : Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 52MB allocation
11-03 11:03:54.388 14412 14497 I art     : Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-03 11:03:54.398 14412 14497 I art     : Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 15% free, 88MB/104MB, paused 238us total 8.159ms
11-03 11:03:54.398 14412 14497 W art     : Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 55161940 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 39MB until OOM"
11-03 11:03:54.408 14412 14497 I art     : Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-03 11:03:54.408 14412 14497 I art     : Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-03 11:03:54.418 14412 14497 I art     : Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(368B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 15% free, 88MB/104MB, paused 4.430ms total 7.573ms
11-03 11:03:54.418 14412 14497 I art     : Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-03 11:03:54.418 14412 14497 I art     : Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-03 11:03:54.428 14412 14497 I art     : Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 15% free, 88MB/104MB, paused 264us total 8.668ms
11-03 11:03:54.428 14412 14497 I art     : Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 52MB allocation
11-03 11:03:54.428 14412 14497 I art     : Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-03 11:03:54.438 14412 14497 I art     : Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 15% free, 88MB/104MB, paused 240us total 7.983ms
11-03 11:03:54.438 14412 14497 I art     : Starting a blocking GC HomogeneousSpaceCompact
11-03 11:03:54.458 14412 14497 I art     : HomogeneousSpaceCompact marksweep + semispace GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 15% free, 88MB/104MB, paused 21.833ms total 21.833ms
11-03 11:03:54.458 14412 14497 W art     : Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 55161940 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 39MB until OOM"
11-03 11:03:54.458 14412 14497 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-2-thread-2
11-03 11:03:54.458 14412 14497 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.myapp.inhouse.test, PID: 14412
11-03 11:03:54.458 14412 14497 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 55161940 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 39MB until OOM
11-03 11:03:54.458 14412 14497 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
11-03 11:03:54.458 14412 14497 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:163)
11-03 11:03:54.458 14412 14497 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:311)
11-03 11:03:54.458 14412 14497 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextString(JSONTokener.java:222)
11-03 11:03:54.458 14412 14497 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:107)
11-03 11:03:54.458 14412 14497 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.json.JSONTokener.readArray(JSONTokener.java:429)
11-03 11:03:54.458 14412 14497 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:103)
11-03 11:03:54.458 14412 14497 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:92)
11-03 11:03:54.458 14412 14497 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
11-03 11:03:54.458 14412 14497 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$25.run(FileUtils.java:560)
11-03 11:03:54.458 14412 14497 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
11-03 11:03:54.458 14412 14497 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
11-03 11:03:54.458 14412 14497 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-03 11:03:54.468   759  1674 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.myapp.inhouse.test/.MainActivity
```

Is it possible to write in the file by chunks in order to avoid this kind of error?

I'm using **cordova 6.4.0** and **cordova-plugin-file 3.0.0**.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: I am too looking for a solution to this, were you able to figure this out ?